# Why Sorting process not happening?

Tags: unity

I created 10000 array and assigned value 1 and 0 to it, then used gizmos to generate 10000 cubes. I paint it black or white depending on the assigned value.

After that I use the bubble sort algorithm to sort the cubes, expecting all black cubes pieled on the bottom but when I run it, the sorting does not happen and I can't spot where my mistake is.

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
   
    int[,] array1 = new int[100, 100];
    int temp;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {



        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)

        {
            for (y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                array1[x, y] = Random.Range(0, 2);

                Debug.Log(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", x, y, array1[x, y]));

            }
        }
        OnDrawGizmos();


    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(0 + x, 0 + y);
                Gizmos.DrawCube(pos1, transform.position);
                Gizmos.color = (array1[x, y] == 1) ? Color.black : Color.white;
            }
        }
    }

    void update()
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 100; z++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < 100 - z; y++)
                {
                    if (array1[x, y] > array1[x, y + 1])
                        temp = array1[x, y];
                    array1[x + 1, y] = array1[x, y];
                    array1[x, y] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
        OnDrawGizmos();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple obvious errors in this code.

1. You are setting the colour to draw the cube *after* you have drawn it. That will apply its colour to the *next* cube you draw, not the one you just drew. Set the colour before you draw the cube.
2. Your bubble sort is comparing the cube with its neighbour above (x, y + 1), but then copying its value to the neighbour beside (x + 1, y).
3. You're copying the value and overwriting what was in the neighbouring spot, not swapping it as a bubble sort should.
4. You're using bubble sort. You're spending 100 * 100 * 100 = 1 000 000 loop iterations on a problem that you can solve a hundred times faster. You're also repeating this sort every frame, when (if you'd done the sort correctly), the results won't change after you've done it once.
5. Or rather, you *would* be repeating the sort every frame, if you'd spelled `Update` correctly with an uppercase U. With a lowercase u, this method won't get called by the engine.
6. You're calling `OnDrawGizmos` manually. This is called by the engine - you should not call it yourself.
7. You're using member variables for things that can easily be temporaries.

You can do this much more efficiently:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSorter : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool[,] cubeIsBlack = new bool[100, 100];


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {    
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)    
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                cubeIsBlack[x, y] = (Random.Range(0, 2) > 0);
    
                Debug.Log($"{x}, {y}, {cubeIsBlack[x, y]}");    
            }
        }

        // We'll sort just once, not every frame.
        Sort();
    }


    // This sorts all the black cubes to the bottom of the column.
    // You can swap x & y to sort along rows instead.
    void Sort() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            // Count how many black cubes are in the column, and remove them.
            int blackCount = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                blackCount += cubeIsBlack[x, y] ? 1 : 0;
                cubeIsBlack[x, y] = false;
            }

            // Replace the black cubes all together at the bottom of the column.
            for (int y = 0; y < blackCount; y++) {
                cubeIsBlack[x, y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                Vector2 position = new Vector2(x, y);
                Gizmos.color = cubeIsBlack[x, y] ? Color.black : Color.white;
                Gizmos.DrawCube(position, Vector3.One);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please allow me to have some time to digest it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `Update()` instead of `update()`. Btw your code in update can be quite slow, so I'd rather run it once instead of every frame.